post process behavior artifacts on new unity versions
I have an old project that I need to run on Unity 2022.3.40. It uses post process behavior and post process works absolutely fine in the editor, just as before migrating to new Unity. But when I make an Android build and run it, bloom makes bright surfaces black or bluish. From what I found, post process behavior shows artifacts on Unity 2018 and newer. I can't switch to post process stack because I'm not able to recreate the effects in there.
Here is how it is in the build:


and here in the editor:


The settings for bloom in the post processing profile:

I'm using post process behavior 1.0.4
The artifacts only happen on mobile. According to RenderDoc, uber shader caused this.

Ok, I found out the solution. It seems that post process behavior shaders use half precision float in half of its computations, it can very easily overflow here, especially if we take HDR it uses into account. The trick why it works on PC is that their GPUs just don't have half precision floats. Yeah, there is still half type, but it will be just forced to float by either compiler or driver. I just opened directory with post process shaders with VS Code and replaced in all files half with float using search.
